# passing value to a dynamic created function in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I am having some problems while creating a dynamic webpage in javascript.

My idea is to read a list of events and people signed up on them. I create a page with all events (each event is a button) and clicking on one of them, see the list of users.

This works fine. But now, I am adding a button to export some of these users to an excel file. And I want to add a button with an onClick function like this:

```
...onclick=functionÇ(id_Event, numberOfUsers, listOfUsers)...
```

Inside of the html code generated by javascript. I found some problems also doing like this so I changed so:

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type","button");
input.setAttribute("value","Exportar a Excel CSV");
input.onclick = function() {
    saveExcelFunctionControl(arrayNumberUsersInEvents[i], response);
};

td.appendChild(input);
document.getElementById("added"+element[i].id_Event).appendChild(td);
```

I created a global array called arrayNumberUSersInEvents in which I am adding in each possition, people subscribed. i, is the id counter for each position.

But even this, I am getting an undefined while reading the value of the firsdt parameter. I think it is a problem of dynamic data, I am not executing the function I want to each time I click the button. Do you know how to do something like this?

To sum up: My problem is that I want to pass some arguments to a function in a dynamic created page. I don't know how to pass the data and read the correct parameters inside.

I added my code because one user asked for it:

```
for(i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
                                             $(".eventsControl").append(
                                        '<li     id="listControl'+ element[i].id_Event +'">'+
                                    '<a href="#EventControl' + element[i].id_Event + '"' + 'data-transition="slidedown">'+
                                    '<img class="crop" src= "' + element[i].image + '"  />'+
                                    '<h2>' + element[i].name + '</h2>'+
                                    '<p>' + "Desc:  " + element[i].description +'</p>'+
                                    '</a>'+
                                    '</li>'
                                ).listview('refresh');
                         //console.log(response);

                            //BUCLE for setting all users in each event. Better use some string and after, join all of them
                                header = ' <div  width="100%" data-theme = "e" data-role="page" id='+ element[i].id_Event +
                                 ' data-url="EventControl' + element[i].id_Event + '"> ' +
                                 ' <div data-theme = "a" data-role="header"><h1>Lista de Asistencia</h1> ' + 
                                 ' <a href="#controlList" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a></div>'+
                                 ' <div data-role="content"> ' + 
                                 ' <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align: center">' +
                                 ' <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">';

                                 //header = header + '<input data-theme = "c" onclick="saveExcelFunctionControl(this)" id="saveExcelControl' + element[i].id_Event + '" type="button" value = "Guardar a excel"></br>';

                                eval('var numberUsers' +element[i].id_Event + "=1");
                                arrayNumberUsersInEvents[i] = 0; 
                                if(response.length>0){
                                    bucle = ' <table width="100%" border="1" align="left"><tr>'+

                                            ' <th>Nombre</th>'+
                                            ' <th>Primer apellido</th>'+
                                            ' <th>Segundo apellido</th>'+
                                            ' <th>NIF</th>'+
                                            ' <th>Asistencia</th>'+
                                            ' </tr>';

                                    for(iData = 0; iData < response.length; iData++){
                                        if(element[i].id_Event == response[iData].id_Event){
                                            //console.log(response[iData].name);
                                                bucle = bucle + '<tr><td>'+ eval('numberUsers' +element[i].id_Event) +'</td><td>'+ response[iData].name +'</td><td>'+ 
                                                response[iData].surname1 +'</td><td>'+ 
                                                response[iData].surname2 +'</td><td>'+ 
                                                response[iData].NIF + '</td>'+
                                                '<td> '+
                                                    '<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox'+element[i].id_Event+'_'+iData+'" name="option'+iData+'" value="'+iData+'">  '+
                                                '</td>'+


                                                '</tr>';    

                                            eval('numberUsers' +element[i].id_Event + "++");
                                            arrayNumberUsersInEvents[i] = arrayNumberUsersInEvents[i]+1;             
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //header = header + '<input data-theme = "a" onclick="saveExcelFunctionControl(\""element[i].id_Event "\","" + numberUsers + "\",\"" + response+ "\"")" id="saveExcelControl' + element[i].id_Event + '" type="button" value = "Guardar a excel"></br>';
                                    //header = header + '<input data-theme = "a" onclick="saveExcelFunctionControl(""+numberUsers+"")" id="saveExcelControl' + element[i].id_Event + '" type="button" value = "Guardar a excel"></br>';
                                    bucle = bucle + '</table>';
                                    $("#controlList").after(header + bucle + '<div id=added'+element[i].id_Event+'></div>');


var td = document.createElement("td");
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type","button");
input.setAttribute("value","Exportar a Excel CSV");
input.onclick = function() {
    saveExcelFunctionControl(arrayNumberUsersInEvents[i], response);
};

td.appendChild(input);
document.getElementById("added"+element[i].id_Event).appendChild(td);


                                }


                }

                },
       error: function(xhr, status, message) { alert("Status: " + status + "\nControlGetEventsRegister: " + message); }
    });
```

Comment: And where is `i` coming from ?

Comment: i is a counter for reading all events. It plus 1 each row. So the first event in list will be 0, the second 1...

Comment: Then show us how you do that ?

Comment: I already added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **closure** to pass parameters to dynamically created onclick handler:

```
input.onclick = (function() {
    var arr = arrayNumberUsersInEvents[i];
    var resp = response;
    return function() {
        saveExcelFunctionControl(arr, resp);
    }
})();
```

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Adding the last () makes the button doesn't appear and also the function is launch when the page loads

Comment: @Biribu last () just calls anonymous function that return onclick handler function.. Maybe error somewhere else

Comment: I couldn't got it working. I solved in other way. Anyway, I made this works in a simple example so I guess it works and I have other error I haven't seen yet. Solved tag goes for you. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
var input = "<input type='button' value='Exportar a Excel CSV'";
input+= "onclick='saveExcelFunctionControl(""" +arrayNumberUsersInEvents[i]+""","""+ response+""");' />";

};

td.textContent=input;
document.getElementById("added"+element[i].id_Event).appendChild(td);
```

try this way